# Python: How do I check email with a loop without there being a message in the inbox?

Tags: python, imaplib, gmail-imap

```
import serial
import imaplib
from time import sleep

IMAP_SERVER='imap.gmail.com'
IMAP_PORT=993
ser= serial.Serial ('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)

M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(IMAP_SERVER, IMAP_PORT)
rc, resp = M.login('user@gmail.com', 'password')
print rc, resp

while True: 
    M.select()
    for msg_num in M.search("INBOX", "UNDELETED")[1][0].split():
        msg = M.fetch('1', '(BODY.PEEK[TEXT])') 
        String = msg[1][0][1][139:161]
        print String
        if String == "This is just a test...":
            ser.write('0')
    sleep(1)
```

I'm a new beginner in python programming and the above python code is one that I'm using for a program I want to do. When I run this in a terminal I get the response that I have authenticated my account and then it displays the message between characters 139 & 161, which is the following in the example email:

This is just a test...

This is printed out in the terminal. If I delete the message in my inbox this comes out:

```
String = msg[1][0][1][139:161]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable
```

I believe that this is due to that I don't have any messages in the inbox. Now what I want to do is that if there are no messages to run again and again until a message shows up in my inbox & do an according action pending on the message

Comment: Variable should have lowercase names (e.g. `s` vs. `String`). [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is a good source for starting Python programmers.

Comment: You should use imaplib2's idle instead of repeatedly running a search. That way you only need to check when the server tells you that something has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty fix is to catch the `TypeError`. Something like this:

```
try:
    String = msg[1][0][1][139:161]
except TypeError:
    continue
```

That said, this could stand to be improved. For one thing, you can use

```
if 'This is just a test...' in String:
    # ...
```

instead of slicing your message body to bits and relying on exact placement. You might also want to confirm that `msg[1][0]` is the body tuple, or iterate through the items in `msg` until you find it.

You may also be interested in reading [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Others are more likely to be able to quickly read your code if you stick to it when you can.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm a beginner and this was a great fix. Thank you!